# c# Datagridview bindingsource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is a current clip of my program, as it is, the datagridview is disconnected to the datatable such that if I change anything on the dataviewgrid, it wont reflect in the datatable... How can I make it so that any edits on the datagridview can be reflected to atleast the datatable?

```
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OFD.Title = "CSV File";
        OFD.Filter = "Spreadsheet | *.csv";
        OFD.ShowDialog();

        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(csv_SeatingPlan));
        try
        {
            csv_SeatingPlan[] container = engine.ReadFile(OFD.FileName) as csv_SeatingPlan[];
            CSV_Seating_Plan = new List<csv_SeatingPlan>(container);

            DataTable DT_student_Records = new DataTable();
            DT_student_Records.Columns.Add("Exam_Period", typeof(string));
            DT_student_Records.Columns.Add("Exam_Code", typeof(string));
            DT_student_Records.Columns.Add("Student_ID", typeof(string));
            DT_student_Records.Columns.Add("Student_Name", typeof(string));
            DT_student_Records.Columns.Add("Candidate_Number", typeof(string));


            foreach (csv_SeatingPlan row in CSV_Seating_Plan)
            {
                DT_student_Records.Rows.Add(row.examperiod, row.exam_Code, row.id_Student, row.name_Student, row.candidatenum_Student);
            }

            DT_student_Records.DefaultView.Sort = "Candidate_Number ASC";
            this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 11);
            //bindingCSVSP.DataSource = DT_student_Records;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DT_student_Records;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to propagate your changes to the underlying data source (in your case the table), you should use the [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)  object. An example of how to do this is at the bottom of the linked page.

Comment: hey, I got rid of the datatables and instead used list binding having datagridview.source = list... but when I run the datagridview, it doesnt allow me to change anything, even though I already had the dgv.readonly = false

Comment: In this case, use the BindingList instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx

Comment: I did but the bindinglist still doesnt make me edit the values from the datagridview :/ does it now need an actionevent?

Comment: ah sorry for the hassle i just read a sample and it says i need to add eventhandlers... AddingNewEventHandler and ListChangedEventHandler sorry for the hassle. thanks